# How to make a progress bar that updates itself after time

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, progress-bar

Im trying to make a math program, and wanted to add the option for the program to be canceled after a set amount of time (1,2 or 3 minutes).
I wrote this code for it (tkinter):

```
# functions:
benötigt = 100
def zeit_update():
    global dashed

    if dashed <= benötigt:
        _w2.progress['value'] = dashed
        _w2.progress.after(1000, zeit_update())
        dashed += 1
    else:
        start_stop()
```

(the function start_stop() stops the program)
This is the function that is supposed to update the progress bar _w2.progress by 1 every 1000 milliseconds. But when it gets called (by a 1 time button press, which activates the loop), i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Nutzer\Desktop\gui\gui2temp3.py", line 1302, in <lambda>
    self.min_1.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: gui2temp3_support.minuten_1(e))
  File "C:\Users\Nutzer\Desktop\gui\gui2temp3_support.py", line 1038, in minuten_1
    _w2.progress.after(1000,zeit_update())
  File "C:\Users\Nutzer\Desktop\gui\gui2temp3_support.py", line 140, in zeit_update
    _w2.progress.after(10000, zeit_update())
  File "C:\Users\Nutzer\Desktop\gui\gui2temp3_support.py", line 140, in zeit_update
    _w2.progress.after(10000, zeit_update())
  File "C:\Users\Nutzer\Desktop\gui\gui2temp3_support.py", line 140, in zeit_update
    _w2.progress.after(10000, zeit_update())
  [Previous line repeated 983 more times]
  File "C:\Users\Nutzer\Desktop\gui\gui2temp3_support.py", line 139, in zeit_update
    _w2.progress['value'] = dashed
  File "C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1649, in __setitem__
    self.configure({key: value})
  File "C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1638, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1628, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
  File "C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1465, in _options
    cnf = _cnfmerge(cnf)
  File "C:\Users\Nutzer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 103, in _cnfmerge
    if isinstance(cnfs, dict):
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Ive tried so many different methods on fixing this problem, including highering the recursion limit but nothing worked. Im litterally completly stuck and dont know what to do. :(

here is the full code:

````
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter.constants import *


dashed = 0
def main(*args):
    global root
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', root.destroy)
    global _top2, _w2
    _top2 = root
    _w2 = spiel(_top2)
    zeit_update()
    root.mainloop()




class spiel:
    def __init__(self, top=None):

        _bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _fgcolor = '#000000'  # X11 color: 'black'
        _compcolor = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana1color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana2color = '#ececec' # Closest X11 color: 'gray92'

        self.style = ttk.Style()

        if sys.platform == "win32":
            self.style.theme_use('winnative')
        self.style.configure('.',background=_bgcolor)
        self.style.configure('.',foreground=_fgcolor)
        self.style.map('.',background=
            [('selected', _compcolor), ('active',_ana2color)])

        top.geometry("600x450+475+21")
        top.minsize(600, 450)
        top.maxsize(600, 450)
        top.resizable(0,0)
        top.title("mathe")
        top.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        top.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        top.configure(highlightcolor="black")

        self.top = top
        self.Frame1 = tk.Frame(self.top)
        self.Frame1.place(relx=0.017, rely=0.133, relheight=0.856
                          , relwidth=0.975)
        self.progress = ttk.Progressbar(self.Frame1)
        self.progress.place(relx=0.034, rely=0.286, relwidth=0.94, relheight=0.0
                            , height=22)
        self.progress.configure(length="100")
        self.progress.configure(value=1)


def zeit_update():
        global dashed

        dashed += 10
        _w2.progress['value'] = dashed
        _w2.progress.after(10000, zeit_update())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    ```
````

Comment: Your code is not complete. It's impossible to reproduce the problem. Please consider editing the question

Comment: Could you go into detail what the after() method of progress is doing and how it works? It's apparently a method that requires a callback so a function and not a function call.

Comment: `.after(1000, zeit_update())` delete the parentheses. `.after(1000, zeit_update)` should work.

Comment: Thingamabobs, thank you. You are the greatest person to ever exist on earth. It worked. Im was so happy, when the code compiled with no errors. :DDD

Comment: Lmao, @User1986 Glad I was able to help you out. Besides, the reason is that the after method takes a function object as argument and calls it after time. If you call it by yourself it trys to get the return value and calls the function immediately, which results in your case in an infinite loop.